# Null check and empty string check in makefile

Tags: linux, makefile, gnu-make

I have two variables in the makefile they can be `empty` or having `empty string` OR `valid string`

I need to error exit in case either of the variable is `empty` or `empty string`

Here is simple makefile I am using

```
ABC := ""
XYZ := hello

all:
ifeq ($(and $(ABC),$(XYZ)),)
    $(error "Either of var is null")
endif
    @echo "Done"
```

With this I get output as `Done` While I want it to fail.

If I change `ifeq` condition as follows,
`ifeq ($(and $(ABC),$(XYZ)),"")` then in following condition make is not error exiting

```
ABC :=
XYZ := hello

all:
ifeq ($(and $(ABC),$(XYZ)),"")
    $(error "Either of var is null")
endif
    @echo "Done"
```

**One solution could be as follows,(?)**

```
ABC := hello
XYZ := hello

all:
ifeq ($(and $(ABC),$(XYZ)),)
    $(error "Var is null")
endif
ifeq ($(and $(ABC),$(XYZ)),"")
    $(error "Var is null2")
endif

    @echo "Done"
```

However I feel there could a better way of doing it, Any suggestions ?

**EDIT**

**Just to explain what I want is**,

```
if ABC is empty string(ABC := "") OR empty(ABC := )  OR
   XYZ is empty string(XYZ := "") OR empty(XYZ := )
   $(error "empty string or null")
endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to be clear, make doesn't care about quotes in any way.  When make talks about "empty" variables it means variable with no value.  If you write:

```
ABC := ""
```

then that variable has a value, the literal characters `""`.  To make, that's no different from assigning `ab` etc. (at least in how make interprets those values).

For your problem you can use something like:

```
ifeq (,$(subst ",,$(ABC)$(XYZ)))
    $(error empty string or null)
endif
```

which will replace all quotes with nothing; if the result of that is an empty string then you know the variables were either empty or contained nothing but quotes.

Note that this will also cause variables that contain only one quote, or more than two quotes, to be considered empty; e.g.,

```
ABC := "
XYZ := """""""""""""
```

will also be considered empty.  If you really want only to consider exactly two quotes to be empty then you need something more fancy.

Comment: Thank you for reply, I will check and will get back. However I would prefer more cleaner solution.

Comment: You'll have to define what you mean by "more cleaner solution".  Which part of this solution do you find lacking?

Comment: Apologies I misunderstood that if value contains values quotes e.g. `"value"` That will also be considered empty. I tested your suggestion and it seems to be fine. There only one problem, error is reported only when both of them are null, I want to error out when either of variable is null. I know it can be done by separate `ifeqs` however wanted to check if its possible in single `ifeq` .

Answer (score 0):

Ack, I don't have enough reputation to make comments, but it appears as though none of the above actually answer your question.   Concatenation is the functional equivalent of `$(or`, not `$(and`, so `$(ABC)$(XYZ)` is not equivalent to `$(and $(ABC),$(XYZ))` (and `$(subst ",,""xxx)` will not be blank either).

Also, your second example in your question will not work, as if `$(ABC)` is `""`, then `$(and $ABC,xxx)` will be `xxx`, not `""`.

What you need is a macro, say `unquote` to remove the qoutes, and then do:

```
unquote=$(subst ",,$(1))
ifeq ($(and $(call unquote,$(ABC)),$(call unquote,$(XYZ))),)
```

Which is a bit ugly.   You could of course change unquote to only simplify empty quoted strings.